# Google Maps Place Result how to translate into multiple languages

Tags: api, autocomplete, maps, multilingual

I use the Places Autocomplete Service to search for a specific address. The Adress should be stored to database on my model to know where it is located. My site is multi lingual and I have to print the adress (e.g. the country names) in the choosen language. Also I have to filter the models by country or city's name.

Is there a way to get the PlaceResult in multiple languages?

I use the Javascript API in the version v3.8